# how to remove BS modal on close (it loads on scroll() )

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

I've got this conditional that launch a modal window after scrolling at least 200 px.
How do I to remove this modal on close and prevent to keep appearing on scrolling?

$(window).scroll(function() {

```
var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

if ( scrollTop > 200 ) {

    // Modal Suscribe box
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#suscribe').modal('show');
    }, 4000);

} 
//code goes on with other functions...
```

The **HTML** is like BS example page:

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">X</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
```

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i understand from your requirement is "Modal window should be appear only once scroll size is >200 and if closed by user, it should never appear." For this you could achieve this using one bool variable:

```
window.is_once_opened  = false;
$(window).scroll(function() {    
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();    
  if ( scrollTop > 200 && !is_once_opened ) {    
    is_once_opened  = true;
    // Modal Suscribe box
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#suscribe').modal('show');
    }, 4000);
  }
}
```

Please let me know if you want something different.